# React Native + Jest: why do I need to mock dependencies?

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am fairly new to React Native, transitioning from iOS. I started experimenting with testing with Jest, and pretty soon discovered that I need to mock node modules, if not all dependencies. In my case it is `AsyncStorage`.

My question is not how to mock, for that I've found many guides, but rather why do I even need to mock to make the tests work? Please assume I am not interested in changing the behaviour of `AsyncStorage`, I'm simply wondering why the mock is needed to make the test run without errors.

A broader question: what is the build process that happens when I test an app?

Comment: Because Jest runs a test not in RN app but in Node that doesn't have APIs you talk about. Regardless of AsyncStorage, mocking is needed not just run test without errors but to test exactly your units and not third-party ones and to avoid tests to affect each other through third-party unit.

Comment: So I only have access to my own defined API and node Api?

Comment: Jest provides fake DOM for testing but since it's not web app it's not relevant. There are some parts of RN ecosystem that are platform-independent and can work without mocking, and there are some that can't. In isolated unit testing, every unit that is not tested unit needs to be mocked as a rule of thumb.